# Bootstrap columns stacking vertically rather than horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Right now I have two large columns that are stacking vertically like on top of one another. I want them to be | 1 | 2 | side by side so the user can see both columns at the same time. I'm mainly looking for any tips or things that I can try to help fix this. My code is too long to post all of it on here but I'll just post the main divs. There are a couple of tabs that control which page the user is on. It worked before, but I must have done something make the right column drop below the left.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" style="max-width: 95%;">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="allTabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="homePage" href="#" onclick="alertFunction()">EBSP Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="tv" onClick="openTab(event, 'tv_systems')">FM Broadcast</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="transline" onClick="openTab(event, 'transmission')"> Transmission Line & Power Analysis</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="print" onClick="openTab(event, 'print_pdf')">Print</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- tv systems tab -->
  <form target="_blank" method="post">
    <div class="tabContent" id="tv_systems">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <!-- main left column -->
          <div class="row align-items-start">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
          <!-- Second Column right -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pageValidation" class="errorText"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstrap link in header. After that you will find vertical alignment.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="max-width: 95%;">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="allTabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="homePage" href="#" onclick="alertFunction()">EBSP Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="tv" onClick="openTab(event, 'tv_systems')">FM Broadcast</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="transline" onClick="openTab(event, 'transmission')"> Transmission Line & Power Analysis</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="nav-link" id="print" onClick="openTab(event, 'print_pdf')">Print</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- tv systems tab -->
  <form target="_blank" method="post">
    <div class="tabContent" id="tv_systems">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <!-- main left column -->
          <div class="row align-items-start">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
          <!-- Second Column right -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pageValidation" class="errorText"></div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```